# Как с помощью jquery найти на странице изображение в определенном блоке и добавить это изображение в качестве фона для блока с указанным классом

Tags: jquery

Есть следующая конструкция, в ней необходимо найти `img` в блоке с классом `gamma` и путь/адрес этого изображения назначить в качестве `background-image` для блока с классом `alfa`

```css
.alfa {
  padding: 15px;
  background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .alfa div {
    margin:10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  .gamma img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alfa">

  <div class="delta">
    Он был так угрюм, что его перестали посещать даже мысли.
  </div>

  <div class="gamma">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/T4gQvgx/000.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="omega">
    Мудрость приходит с годами. А потом уходит…
  </div>


</div>
```

Как результат у блока с классом `alfa` должно добавится свойство  `style="background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/T4gQvgx/000.jpg);">` при этом адрес исходного изображения изначально неизвестен, его нужно найти после загрузки страницы в блоке `gamma`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать с помощью скрипта?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, возможно кому-то пригодится:

```js
$('.alfa').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(".gamma img").attr("src") + ')');
```

```css
.alfa {
  padding: 15px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.alfa div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  width: 300px;
}

.gamma img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alfa">

  <div class="delta">
    Он был так угрюм, что его перестали посещать даже мысли.
  </div>

  <div class="gamma">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/T4gQvgx/000.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="omega">
    Мудрость приходит с годами. А потом уходит…
  </div>


</div>
```